# how to specify vc11 lambda calling convention

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, lambda, calling-convention

I want to pass a lambda function pointer, which nested in a class, to the Windows API callback function. I found there is no place for me to specify the `__stdcall` keyword. Some people told me the compile only support `__cdecl`, but after I used nm command to dump the obj file, I found the compile will generate three helper function (`__stdcall`, `__cdecl`, `__fastcall`) concurrently. So my problem is, how can I specify the calling convention?

Those following code are my test code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto func = [](){};
    return 0;
}
```

```
00000000 t ?<helper_func_cdecl>@<lambda_5738939ec88434c53e1a446c47cf2db6>@@CAXXZ
00000000 t ?<helper_func_fastcall>@<lambda_5738939ec88434c53e1a446c47cf2db6>@@CIXXZ
00000000 t ?<helper_func_stdcall>@<lambda_5738939ec88434c53e1a446c47cf2db6>@@CGXXZ
00000000 t ??B<lambda_5738939ec88434c53e1a446c47cf2db6>@@QBEP6AXXZXZ
00000000 t ??B<lambda_5738939ec88434c53e1a446c47cf2db6>@@QBEP6GXXZXZ
00000000 t ??B<lambda_5738939ec88434c53e1a446c47cf2db6>@@QBEP6IXXZXZ
00000000 t ??R<lambda_5738939ec88434c53e1a446c47cf2db6>@@QBEXXZ
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cast it:

```
WinApiFunc(static_cast<void(__stdcall *)()>(func));
```

Or store it into a local variable first:

```
void (__stdcall *funcp)() = func;
WinApiFunc(funcp);
```

Comment: And now i meet another problem: When I use this syntax, I cannot catch any variables, like this: `auto func = [this](){}; void (__stdcall * funcp)() = func;`

Comment: @user1948596 : That's entirely unrelated to calling conventions – only _captureless_ lambdas are convertible to function pointers (how else could state be maintained?). WinAPI functions that take callbacks always also have a `void*`/`LPVOID` state parameter; use that argument to pass `this` (`static_cast` yet again).

Comment: thanks, I use `DWORD` type to transfer `this` pointer, and succeed.

Comment: @user1948596 : `DWORD` will only work on 32-bit platforms – _not_ portable. Which API specifically are you working with? There may be a more straightforward approach...

Comment: `RasDial` API  and store `this` pointer in `RASDIALPARAMS.dwCallbackId`

Comment: @user1948596 : `dwCallbackId` is a `ULONG_PTR` (which _is_ 64-bit portable), not a `DWORD` – if your WinAPI shows it as a `DWORD` then your WinAPI is **very** outdated. :-]

Comment: Yeah, i see `dwCallbackId` is defined as `ULONG_PTR` in the struct defination. However, the callback function define `dwCallbackId` as `DWORD`.. MS is out of dated! not my WinAPI.. :) REF:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377236(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @andrewyoung : Fortunately, it turns out to only be a documentation bug – in the actual Windows SDK (at least as of the Windows 8.0 SDK, which is all I have installed at the moment; hopefully in earlier SDKs as well), the first parameter of `RASDIALFUNC2` is indeed also `ULONG_PTR`. :-]

Comment: _"WinAPI functions that take callbacks always also have a `void*`/`LPVOID` state parameter; use that argument to pass `this` (`static_cast` yet again)."_ - But I can't find `void*`/`LPVOID` parameter, e.g. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine). Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @starriet : It should read 'nearly always'; some poorly-designed APIs lack this.