# ShellExecute in _beginthread

Tags: c++, winapi, shellexecute, beginthread

I need to run for example:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "program.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

as new thread, but I don't know how.
I tried this:

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthread(ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "program.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE), 0, NULL);
WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
```

but obviously it's wrong and can't be compiled. How should I do this?

Comment: Pretty unlikely that you need a new thread. `ShellExecute` is asynchronous. It will return immediately. It won't block on the other process. If you are starting a new process, `CreateProcess` is usually preferable anyway. If you want to do it in a new thread, create a function with this signature `void( __cdecl *start_address )( void * )` that calls `ShellExecute`. Then pass that function to `_beginthread`. If you are using C++ then it would make more sense to use `std::thread` surely.

Comment: The only reason why you'd ever want to run `ShellExecute` (or `ShellExecuteEx` really) in its own thread is, because you need to initialize COM on that thread and it may collide with the calling thread's apartment. However, you aren't even attempting to do that, so it's completely unclear, why you believe that you need to spin up a thread, and then block for it to finish executing. This doesn't implement anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

What you tried is indeed obviously wrong, but the question is whether you understand what's wrong with it. `_beginthread` takes a **pointer to function** (with a specific prototype and calling convention) as its first parameter.

When you write

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthread(ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "program.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE), 0, NULL);
```

you're trying to pass `_beginthread` the **result** of calling `ShellExecute` (in the current thread) which is an `HINSTANCE`, while `_beginthread` expects a `void( __cdecl *)( void * )` (pointer to a `__cdecl` function taking one `void*` parameter and returning `void`).

Not only your code doesn't work because you're trying to pass an `HINSTANCE` where a function to pointer is expected, it doesn't make any sense. Have you read the [`_beginthread` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx)? There are examples there. Plural.

What you meant to write is:

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthread(ThreadFunc, 0, NULL);
```

given:

```
void __cdecl ThreadFunc(void*) {
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "program.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Or, in a more compact and easy to read form:

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)
                 _beginthread([](void*) {
                     ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "program.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);
                 },
                 0, NULL);
```

Unless you're doing something beyong what we're seeing here, David'scomment is probably right and you should be using `std::thread` or `std::async`.

Also note that taking the result of `_beginthread` (int contrast to the result of `_beginthreadex` or `CreateThread`) in unsafe because it may not be valid, as noted in the documentation. Not only that, but `_beginthread`'s return value isn't really a `HANDLE` (it is some sore of a handle, but not a `HANDLE`!), so you can't `WaitForSingleObject` on it:

> The `_beginthreadex` function gives you more control over how the thread is created than `_beginthread` does. The `_endthreadex` function is also more flexible. For example, with `_beginthreadex`, you can use security information, set the initial state of the thread (running or suspended), and get the thread identifier of the newly created thread. **You can also use the thread handle that's returned by `_beginthreadex` with the synchronization APIs, which you cannot do with `_beginthread`**.
>
> It's safer to use `_beginthreadex` than `_beginthread`. If the thread that's generated by `_beginthread` exits quickly, the handle that's returned to the caller of `_beginthread` might be invalid or point to another thread. However, the handle that's returned by `_beginthreadex` has to be closed by the caller of `_beginthreadex`, so it is guaranteed to be a valid handle if `_beginthreadex` did not return an error.

Since this thread only calls one function and exits, it almost maximizes the chance of this handle not being valid. And even if it were, you still couldn't use it to `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: Both the `ThreadFunc` definition as well as the lambda function are missing the respective calling convention. What's more, this answer doesn't even question the necessity for spinning up a new thread, even though there is absolutely nothing in the question indicating, that this were beneficial.

Comment: [`_cdecl` is the default calling convention in MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx). I considrerd this to be common knowledge,but perhaps I was wrong. Though this wasn't states explicitly to be case, since OP is using a function from the MSVC CRT, I deduced him to be using MSVC or a compatible compiler and toolchain.

Comment: The answer doesn't question the necessity of creating a new thread for three reasons: (1) An **answer** is not the place for this, but rather the **comments** area, that indeed was already used for it; (2) It is irrelevant to the answer, and (3) OP stated that he "need[s] to run for **example**: `ShellExecute(...)`". For example. Perhaps he really wants to run something else. Perhaps he runs various tasks, this being only one of them. That was an **example**. The generalized question, **disregarding the example**, was how to call a function on a new thread. This I answered.

Comment: @IInspectable: At least in VC++, and probably other compilers, when a captureless lambda is implicitly converted to a function pointer, it takes on whatever calling convention is needed (the compiler generates code for all calling conventions, and then the linker eliminates any unused code). See [What's the default calling convention of a C++ lambda function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845706/) and [Non-capturing C++ lambdas can be converted to a pointer to function, but what about the calling convention?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150220-00/?p=44623)