# how to use __stdcall to qualify C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, c++11, lambda

**Foreword--I love C++ lambda, if possible I will use it everywhere.**

Now I have a lambda requirement, I need to a __stdcall lambda. But I get the following error message:

```
 error C2664: 'EnumWindows' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda1>' to 'WNDENUMPROC'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Anybody can help me?
Here is my code(**EnumWindowsProc is in the function scope**):

```
        auto EnumWindowsProc = 
            [&](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) mutable -> bool
        {
            return true;
        };
        EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
```

Comment: Try removing the default capture `&`.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I have tried, it doesn't work. i got the same error message.

Comment: I disagree your foreword: lambas should be used only when needed, as everything else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just noticed you have the `visual studio 2010` tag. Stateless lambdas were implemented in VC11. [Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx):

> After lambdas were voted into the Working Paper (v0.9) and mutable
>   lambdas were added (v1.0), the Standardization Committee overhauled
>   the wording, producing lambdas v1.1.  **This happened too late for us
>   to implement in VC10, but we've already implemented it in VC11.**  The
>   lambdas v1.1 wording clarifies what should happen in corner cases like
>   referring to static members, or nested lambdas.  This fixes a bunch of
>   bugs triggered by complicated lambdas.  Additionally, stateless
>   lambdas are now convertible to function pointers in VC11.  This isn't
>   in N2927's wording, but I count it as part of lambdas v1.1 anyways. 
>   It's FDIS 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]/6: **"The closure type for a
>   lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual
>   non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having
>   the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function
>   call operator.** The value returned by this conversion function shall be
>   the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as
>   invoking the closure type’s function call operator."  (**It's even
>   better than that, since we've made stateless lambdas convertible to
>   function pointers with arbitrary calling conventions.  This is
>   important when dealing with APIs that expect __stdcall function
>   pointers and so forth.**)

Also, note that this conversion happens when there is no capture specification as mentioned in the second bolded quote.

Comment: Can I have the lambda function in the function scope to have __stdcall qualifier?

Comment: Interesting, I never knew they could be `__stdcall` when needed.

Comment: @Triumphant: Try casting it `static_cast<bool(__stdcall *)(HWND, LPARAM)>(EnumWindowsProc)`, I don't have a compiler to test right now though. **EDIT** Nevermind, this probably won't work in VC10 because the conversion to function pointer is not implemented.

Comment: @Triumphant I don't think there's a way to get this to work with VC10. As Jesse's answer explains, implicit conversion of stateless lambdas to function pointers is only available from VC11 onwards. If you upgrade to VC11, a `static_cast` with the appropriate calling convention [should fix the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14169489/241631).