# A lambda expression be compiled on 64 platform but causes compile error on 32

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I have a simple lambda expression as:

```
EnumWindows([] (HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) -> BOOL {return FALSE;}, 0);
```

It successfuly is compiled on 64 bit platform but causes following error on 32 bit:

```
[CLANG Error] Unit3.cpp(15): no matching function for call to 'EnumWindows'
  winuser.h(9766): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '<lambda at Unit3.cpp:15:14>' to 'WNDENUMPROC' (aka 'BOOL (*)(HWND, LPARAM) __attribute__((stdcall))') for 1st argument
```

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: This looks relevent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714175/how-to-use-stdcall-to-qualify-c-lambda

Comment: I have seen it, was not useful. It seems it works on 64 bit compile.

Comment: @jcoder: that other question is for Visual Studio, not for C++Builder.

Comment: You need to qualify the lambda as `__stdcall`. 64 bit has only 1 calling convention so this is never a problem. You need to check if your compiler has a dedicated syntax to do that.

Comment: @sbabbi: how to qualify the lambda as __stdcall?

Comment: @mhtaqia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169295/how-to-specify-vc11-lambda-calling-convention

Comment: @sbabbi: Fails. Compile error.

Comment: @mhtaqia Then I guess you are out of luck.