# Creating thread with _beginthreadex, __stdcall and a lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, mingw

I'm using CodeBlocks with mingw, gcc version 5.1.0.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
unsigned int __stdcall doWork(void* data)
{
    if (napolniDrevo())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else in other function:

```
HANDLE m_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &doWork, 0, 0, 0);
```

The code works fine. Today I learned about lambda expressions, and wanted to try it.

So I deleted function `doWork()` and tried to do the same with:

```
auto lambda = [](void* data) WINAPI -> unsigned int {if (napolniDrevo()) return 0; else return 1;};
HANDLE m_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, lambda, 0, 0, 0);
```

But I get error:

```
||=== Build: Release in CtrlData (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||warning: ./wx_pch.h.gch/Debug_wx_pch_h_gch: not used because `__WXDEBUG__' not defined [-Winvalid-pch]|
C:\Users\M0097932\Desktop\CtrlData\CtrlDataMain.cpp||In member function 'void DataGetterFrame::OnButton2Click(wxCommandEvent&)':|
C:\Users\M0097932\Desktop\CtrlData\CtrlDataMain.cpp|551|error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'DataGetterFrame::OnButton2Click(wxCommandEvent&)::<lambda(void*)>' to 'unsigned int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(void*)' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\M0097932\Desktop\CtrlData\CtrlDataMain.cpp|550|note: candidate is: DataGetterFrame::OnButton2Click(wxCommandEvent&)::<lambda(void*)>::operator unsigned int (*)(void*)() const <near match>|
C:\Users\M0097932\Desktop\CtrlData\CtrlDataMain.cpp|550|note:   no known conversion from 'unsigned int (*)(void*)' to 'unsigned int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(void*)'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\process.h|100|note:   initializing argument 3 of 'long unsigned int _beginthreadex(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(void*), void*, unsigned int, unsigned int*)'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I guess I have to put __stdcall somewhere. I didn't find anything by googling yet.

Comment: Since you have lambdas, I suggest you also learn about the [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you, but I have to use _beginthreadex.

Comment: Nah, you don't :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually *almost* works as-is. Lambdas with no captures can convert to function pointers so they are, to a degree, compatible with C-like APIs.

However, `_beginthreadex` is expecting a function pointer to a `__stdcall` function; the "native" function pointer is this; the converted lambda is not.

But Microsoft have kindly made it so that [it can be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14169295/560648)! All you need is a cast to "coerce" the function pointer. This is a little unintuitive because your lambda is already `__stdcall` ([that's what `WINAPI` expands to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348447/560648)), but whatever.

So:

```
auto lambda = [](void* data) WINAPI -> unsigned int
{
    return (napolniDrevo() ? 0 : 1);
};

HANDLE m_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(
    0, 0,
    static_cast<unsigned int(WINAPI*)(void*)>(lambda),
    0, 0, 0
);
```

But actually I'd recommend [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead for clean, portable code!

Comment: Thank you. I looked up std::thread but it doesn't look like good option for me, because I need to check if thread is done (now I use WaitForSingleObject()) and what the thread function returns (GetExitCodeThread()). I know futures are an option, but it seems like extra work for what already works.

Comment: You mean like `myThread.join()`? (The return value is trickier) Honestly though even if you have to jump through one or two minor hoops, it's _well_ worth it overall.

Comment: join() waits for thread to finish if it's still working. While it is working, I have progress bar running in main thread, where I have to check if user pressed "cancel" button on the bar. Created thread (napolniDrevo()) could not finish at all, which means join() wouldn't finish. These are just some problems off the top of my head.

Comment: Okay, then synchronised progress indicators and possibly condition variables are for that. Everything you are doing now you can do with `std::thread`. Try to avoid platform-specific APIs where you don't need them.

Comment: Damn you are correct, I used c++ future and only needed async(), future.wait_for() and future.get(). Much cleaner code. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Have fun!

Comment: Hi,this code seems can not be compiled with latest vs2019. I tried it here https://godbolt.org/z/hsssnPEvq.